# Editing the WordPress Admin Menus

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin, slug

This is a 2 part question.

1. I followed this [guide](https://whiteleydesigns.com/editing-wordpress-admin-menus/) to be able to change an admin menu item, but what is the process to find out what the WordPress menu key is?
   I am using this [theme](https://themeforest.net/item/stack-multipurpose-wordpress-theme-with-variant-page-builder/19707359) but the developer has stopped support and would like to change careers menu and submenu labels.
2. Once the above is done, how to change the hard coded slug & breadcrumbs to match the new menu item?

The goal is to edit the naming structure associated with this but keep its functionality. I found in the theme > Admin > theme_functions.php the code it uses for this part but not sure how to override this in the child theme?

Any help would be great.

```
if( 'career' == $post_type ){
        $slug = get_option('tommusrhodus_careers_slug', 'careers');
        $home .= '<li class="active"><a href="' . esc_url( home_url( "/". $slug ."/" ) ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Careers', 'stack' ) . '</a></li>';
    }
```

Comment: Go to your child theme folder and edit the `theme_functions.php` there. Alternatively, overwrite the functionality with the use of the functions.php file. functions.php is usually loaded as the last php file in terms of functional logic.

Comment: when I put in a rewrite function in to the child theme I get a 404 error.

function change_post_types_slug( $args, $post_type ) {
   
   /*item post type slug*/   
   if ( 'career' === $post_type ) {
      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'candidates';
   }

   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_types_slug', 10, 2 );

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this plugin that has a UI to change everything: https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/